# Select number of answers for each question options by respondent group

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's take a PostgreSQL DB with the following structure:

[image: 4]
(all the relations from top to down are **OneToMany**)

How can we retrieve, for a "**Brandlift**" with a given **campaign_id** :

For each **question**, the number of **answers*** by **brand** by **respondent.segment**

*i.e the count of **anwer_content** rows having a matching **brand id**

Here is an example of desired output given this [dump](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5b9f16f84f06380ce42ea6eed2a5248220210130164644/16f274) [image: 2]

Basically, a brand is just a possible answer/choice option, for a question

You can see the Brandlift as a multiple choice q, which has the same choice options for every question

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output in a usable format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your lastest data, and here is the query.

```
SELECT
    BQ.id as question_id,
    BR.segment_id,
    BB.name AS Brand_Name,
    COUNT(BAC.brand_id) AS Answer_Count
FROM
    PUBLIC.Brandlift B
    LEFT JOIN brandlift_question BQ ON B.campaign_id = BQ.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN brandlift_respondent BR ON B.campaign_id = br.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN brandlift_segment BS ON BR.segment_id = BS.id
    LEFT JOIN brandlift_answer BA ON BQ.id = BA.question_id AND BR.id = BA.respondent_id
    LEFT JOIN brandlift_brand BB ON B.campaign_id = BB.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN brandlift_answer_content BAC ON BA.id = BAC.answer_id AND BB.id = BAC.brand_id
WHERE
    B.campaign_id = '8d8c79ce-188c-4f5e-bd72-edb854faf34c'
GROUP BY
    BQ.id,
    BB.name,
    BR.segment_id,
    BS.name
```

and your result would be
[image]

Comment: Very useful thanks! but I'm still struggling for the last part, I really can't get how to retrieve the correct number of answers. Actually this query returns more answers than there is for a question. 
In fact, for "Count_Answer" column, I need to get the number of answer_content which brand_id matches the row brand. So I think I need an additional output column to join Brandlift_Answer_Content to the query.
If it can help, here is a dump of the DB: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d458341213d11f58b341ef795da4c63c20210130101455/2bd887

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use a composite key made of 'question_id' and 'respondent_id' for the Answer table ? So that I can directly access 'question_id' from an 'answer_content' and by the way it enforces a 'question' to have only 1 'answer' by 'respondent'. Helps me solve 2 at once

Comment: I got your data, now could test my queries. could you use your data and give me your desired output. that would be helpful for me to double check.  for your second question, no need to do that, if you want to be a good database architecture, you have to avoid redundant columns. Since you've already create FK to constraint the relationship between among answer, question and respondent, no more step are needed here.

Comment: Here is a new dump : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5b9f16f84f06380ce42ea6eed2a5248220210130164644/16f274 I just changed the "segment" boolean column of  'brandlift_respondent' to a new table, so that 'brandlift_segment' hasMany 'respondent'. And here is the desired output given this new dump : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrhdh.png

Comment: @Mohs sorry I went shopping yesterday, I've updated the query

Comment: Pretty close!  But with your updated query, when there is more than 1 segment, the 2 last rows when sorted by segment_id, are repeating with the exact same 'question_id', 'segment_id', 'brand_name', but with a 0 (incorrect) count. Based on your answer I came up with another query (http://www.sharemycode.fr/cuh), but it outputs an extra 'total_answers' column. Is it possible to get the same result without it ?

Comment: If this one is correct : http://www.sharemycode.fr/tsv, you can update your answer with it, so I can mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: @Mohs, I updated the query from your last comments, the results looks almost same, but you got the point, join and group by, you could get all the result for that kind of problem. XD

Comment: If you can just rename the "No column name" to "answer_count", and remove the "total_anwers" column from your result screenshot that would be perfect!

Comment: are you able to solve this one too ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997550/select-mcq-answer-count-based-on-previous-questions-answer
(it’s in the continuation of this question)

Comment: @Mohs, yes, that would be better that you put your data here, https://dbfiddle.uk/ including your insert statement and table creation part. so that I could do it without creating my own database

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a127374b9a327204db40dc9f4e769fc1

Comment: came up with a working query, but I'm very curious for advices to make it better, can you check the updated post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997550/select-mcq-answer-count-based-on-previous-questions-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Mohs sry, worked hard yesterday, and I update your post.  thx